# Service probability for M/M/c queue where reneging time depends on service time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

There is an M/M/1 (getting a result for M/M/c is ideal) queue with arrival rate  and service rate  and participants can renege.

However, the difference between normal reneging settings (constant time $\tau$) and this setting is that the participants know its service time ahead of time and the time to renege is a function of its service time (sampling from exponential). Let's say the function is a linear function of its service time $ w(\cdot) = a \cdot s$, where $ s \sim Exp(\mu)$ and $ a $ is a constant.

There is no balking.

What would be the expression for the steady-state probability that a participant receives service?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See here for exponential reneging times: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/service-probability-for-m-m-1-queue-with-reneging

and recall that if $X\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\mu)$ then $aX\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\mu/a)$ for $a>0$.